# Faulty /etc/fstab preventing Proxmox boot

Tags: boot, fstab, proxmox

I've added a single entry to a `/etc/fstab`:

```
mount //sambashare /media/sambashare
```

Running `mount -a` worked just fine, I could access all the files. However, after a reboot, I'm faced with this error:

```
etho0 is in forwarding mode
Waiting for vmbr1 to get ready (MAXWAIT is 32 seconds).
```

Recurring reboots do not help. I'm strongly assuming it's related to this fstab entry, as I hadn't done any other changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is as designed.

As you've added a network share to your fstab, networking needs to be up before it can be mounted.

You've created a bridge (vmbr1), which can needs time to set up if [STP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol) is enabled, usually 30-40 seconds.

Disabling STP might work, but might be a bad idea considering your setup.

Another solutions would be mounting the share manually in /etc/rc.local (or similar) or using autofs.

Answer (score 2):

`mount` seems like an incorrect value for the first field in your fstab and looks like you simply copied a `mount` commandline.

> (`man 5 fstab`) ... The first field in `/etc/fstab`, (fs_spec), describes the block special device or remote filesystem to be mounted. For ordinary mounts it will hold (a link to) a block special device node  (as  created  by  mknod(8)) for the device to be mounted, like `/dev/cdrom` or `/dev/sdb7`.
>   For NFS mounts one will have :, e.g., ‘knuth.aeb.nl:/’.

I would expect something like this instead in /etc/fstab:

```
//sambashare /media/sambashare cifs credentials=/etc/smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,_netdev
```

The `_netdev` mount option is strongly recommended, it will delay mounting file-systems that require network access until after the network connection has been established, preventing time-outs.

Comment: Updating the line to `//share /media/share cifs iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,_netdev` yields the same error. So I might stick with mounting in `rc.local`, right?